# implementing webhook subscription into an API resource

Tags: node.js, express, webhooks, api-design

Consider the following vanilla api resource with the following routes:

```
`POST` `{{baseurl}}/api/v1/users`    
//with request body of 
{
    "username":"adam12",
    "password":"abc123"
}

`GET` `{{baseurl}}/api/v1/users`   
`GET` `{{baseurl}}/api/v1/users/:id`   
`PUT` `{{baseurl}}/api/v1/users/:id`   
`DELETE` `{{baseurl}}/api/v1/users/:id`
```

where `{{baseurl}}` is `localhost:3000`.

I have the code for a working implementation of this here: https://github.com/mmcguff/webhookLearning

At this point clients interacting with this `users` resource must send `GET` requests in order to get made aware of changes to this resources.  If you were needing real time data from this resource you would have to create a polling loop which consumes resources on both the client at the server answering these requests.

I know the right solution for this problem is to implement a webhook subscription for this resource but I have found no clear best practice type information on how to do this in node.js.  The package I found in npm has very few downloads at the moment which leads me to believe there must be a better way that others are using.

Any help on what migration from a vanilla API to a webhook API would be great for me and everyone in the community.

Comment: Another developer suggested that perhaps I could socket.io to help with solving this problem but I am not really sure.  Anyone else know if this could be a help and how it could used to create a kind of subscription to events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common to use a queue for this type of thing. GitHub, for example, open sourced one for Ruby called [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) a long while back. In Node specifically, you could look at [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull). Bull uses Redis for storage of queued events similar to resque. Workers subscribe to events they care about and process them accordingly.

Now for a practical but limited example for your use case:

```
const Queue = require('bull');
const rp = require('request-promise');

const userQueue = new Queue('user');

app.post(`/v1/users`, (req, res) => {
  userQueue.add({username: req.body.username, email: req.body.email});
  return res.send(`OK`);
});

const userSubscribers = [
  {
    hookUrl: `http://example.com/user-hook`
  }
];

userQueue.process(job => {
  return Promise.all(userSubscribers.map(subscriber => {
    const options = {
      method: `POST`,
      uri: subscriber.hookUrl,
      body: job.data,
      json: true
    };
    return rp(options);
  });
});
```

For different tradeoffs, you could use Kafka instead of webhooks.

Comment: Thanks John for you answer.  This is very close to what I ended up creating for this.  Now I am working through how to subscribe to specific events.  If you have any ideas about this please let me know.